# Eu consigo passar a cor como parametro no dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, cores

Container(
height: 140,
width: 100,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.blue,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
border: Border.all(color: variavel, width: 5),
),
),

Answer (score -2):

consegue

```
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color variavel;
  const ResultTextWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.variavel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 140,
      width: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25), 
        border: Border.all(color: variavel, width: 5), 
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).